# How to map several list<property> to view model using automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

Im trying to figure out to how to map a list to an object containing an identical list property

I have a view model that looks like this:

```
public class GenerateCodeVM
{
    public List<AnimalVM> Animal { get; set; }

    public List<RegionVM> Region { get; set; }
}

public class AnimalVM
{
    public int? AnimalID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    public DateTime? LastUpdated { get; set; }
}

public class RegionVM
{
    public int? RegionID { get; set; }

    public string RegionName { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller I have:

```
GenerateCodeVM generateCodeVM = new GenerateCodeVM();
AnimalRepository animalRepository = new AnimalRepository();
List<Animal> animal = animalRepository.GetAll().ToList();
RegionRepository regionRepository = new RegionRepository();
List<Region> region = regionRepository.GetAll().ToList();

generateCodeVM = Mapper.Map<List<Region>, GenerateCodeVM> (region);
generateCodeVM = Mapper.Map<List<Animal>, GenerateCodeVM>(animal);
```

How do I configure the mappings in automapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This first bit is fine

```
GenerateCodeVM generateCodeVM = new GenerateCodeVM();
AnimalRepository animalRepository = new AnimalRepository();
List<Animal> animal = animalRepository.GetAll().ToList();
RegionRepository regionRepository = new RegionRepository();
List<Region> region = regionRepository.GetAll().ToList();
```

These next to lines aren't.

```
generateCodeVM = Mapper.Map<List<Region>, GenerateCodeVM> (region);
generateCodeVM = Mapper.Map<List<Animal>, GenerateCodeVM>(animal);
```

I would merely map into the `generateCodeVM` object rather than to the whole thing.

So you need to mappings set up.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Region, RegionVM>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Animal, AnimalVM>();
```

Then you can use the `project` extension method in `AutoMapper`. **As long as the `GetAll()` is returning an `IQueryable<>`**.

```
GenerateCodeVM generateCodeVM = new GenerateCodeVM();

AnimalRepository animalRepository = new AnimalRepository();
RegionRepository regionRepository = new RegionRepository();

List<Animal> animal = animalRepository.GetAll().Project().To<AnimalVM>().ToList();

List<Region> region = regionRepository.GetAll().Project().To<RegionVM>.ToList();
```

Then just assign these projected lists to the `generateCodeVM`

```
generateCodeVM.Animal = animal;
generateCodeVM.Region = region;
```

#### Hints and Tips

If you don't want to use `Project` you can simple do:

```
List<Region> region = regionRepository.GetAll().ToList();
var mappedRegions = Mapper.Map<List<RegionVM>>(region);
```

You don't need to change the `CreateMap` at all to support this, it is supported out of the box.

I would pluralise your variable names that refer to lists, so that it makes your code clearer to you and anyone else looking at it (e.g. us/me on SO).

```
List<Region> region = regionRepository.GetAll().ToList();
```

Should be

```
List<Region> regions = regionRepository.GetAll().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a really odd solution, the last two lines overwrite the same variable. I suggest you'd replace the last two lines in the controller with

```
GenerateCodeVM generateCodeVM = new GenerateCodeVM();
generateCodeVM.Animal = Mapper.Map<List<AnimalVM>>(animal);
generateCodeVM.Region = Mapper.Map<List<RegionVM>>(region);
```